# How to get grouping of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

```
I have a table like this:
id  name
1   washing
1   cooking
1   cleaning
2   washing
2   cooking
3   cleaning
```

and I would like to have a following grouping

```
id  name                      count
1   washing,cooking,cleaning    3
2   washing,cooking             2
3   cleaning                    1
```

I have tried to group by ID but can only show count after grouping by

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(name)
FROM WORK
GROUP BY id
```

But this will only give the count and not the actual combination of names.

I am new to SQL. I know it has to be relational but there must be some way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in postgresql you can use array_agg

```
SELECT id, array_agg(name),  COUNT(*)
FROM WORK
GROUP BY id
```

in mysql   you can use group_concat

```
SELECT id, group_concate(name),  COUNT(*)
FROM WORK
GROUP BY id
```

or for redshift

```
SELECT id, listagg(name),  COUNT(*)
FROM WORK
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I get this
```function array_agge(character varying) does not exist ```

Comment: answer uodated .. is array_agg

Comment: I still get same error
```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function array_agg(character varying) does not exist;
```

Comment: which db you are really using .. mysql? .. postgresql .?? .. or some  other db ..  ???

Comment: Thanks. The listagg seems to work, but its not grouping. I am getting like:
```
cleaning 1
cleaning 1
cleaning 1
```
what i want is cleaning 3

Comment: are you sure you have not empty string ..check for the real content of your data

Comment: Yes, there is no empty string. Grouping doesnt seem to work